# Ext.Msg.confirm() is not working on tap of image in sencha touch

Tags: sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I want to show confirmation alert message to user on tap of the image. in the listeners i have defined tap function, within that defined Ext.Msg.confirm(""). when i tap the image i am not getting confirmation message. so below of this one i have defined normal alert message "Hi". after this one i am able to see only normal alert message "HI". not getting confirmation message. ***on image tap i need to display confirmation message to user to confirm Yes/No.*** same code i have used for button handler function. Ext.Msg.confirm(""). message working fine. is image tap support  Ext.Msg.confirm("") or not? if possible then how to achieve this one. any one tell me how to do.

Here is Mycode:

```
                              {
                                        xtype: 'image',
                                        src: 'Imagepath',
                                        listeners: {
                                                tap: function () {

                                                // confiramation message
                                                Ext.Msg.confirm(
                                                   "Confirmation",
                                                   "Are you sure you want to proceed?",
                                                   function (btn) {
                                                       if (btn === 'yes') {
                                                           Ext.Msg.alert("You have selected Yes", "");
                                                       }
                                                       else {
                                                           Ext.Msg.alert("You have selected NO", "");
                                                       }
                                                   },
                                                   this
                                                );

                                              //Normal alert message
                                              alert("Hi");
                                            }
                                    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried this code in Sencha Touch documentation live code preview and it works fine...

```
var img = Ext.create('Ext.Img', {
    src: 'http://www.sencha.com/assets/images/sencha-avatar-64x64.png',
    height: 64,
    width: 64,
    listeners: {
        tap: function(){
             Ext.Msg.confirm(
             "Confirmation",
             "Are you sure you want to proceed?",
             function (btn) {
                 if (btn === 'yes') {
                    Ext.Msg.alert("You have selected Yes", "");
                 }
                 else {
                    Ext.Msg.alert("You have selected NO", "");
                 }
             },
             this
       );}
    }
});
```

Try to follow this way and hope it fixes your problem.

Comment: ya it is working...I have made mistakes in my code, so it is not working. i got the solution...thank you..help ful